# Process of finding a solution for a problem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I have a question that doesn't need an answer, just an explanation.

Prove that if $A$ is nilpotent, then $I+A$ is invertible.

The solution is:

Given that $A^k=0$ for some integer $k$, you can say that
$I - A^k = I$
you can factor this as
$(I + A)(I - A + A^2 - A^3 +\cdots+(-A)^{k-1}).$

My question is how should I come up with the statement that $I-A^k=I$? Where do I get the insight to figure out that $I-A^k=I$?

Thanks.

Comment: The definition of a nilpotent matrix is: there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $A^k=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is just the definition of nilpotent matrix (*I think that you mean by $A$ a matrix but this definition is true in any  ring*):

**Definition:** A matrix $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb F)$ is said nilpotent if there's some $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $A^k=0$.

**Added** The question is to prove that $I+A$ is invertible that's means there's some matrix $B$ such that $(I+A)B=I$ which is equivalent to $B=(I+A)^{-1}$.

The idea is to use  a result from analysis: we know that
$$\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^k,\quad |x|<1$$
and if we substitute $x$ by $A$ (*formally*) and since $A$ is nilpotent so the infinite sum is indeed a finite sum and we find the desired result.

Comment: @AbhishekMallela I edited my answer.

Comment: @AbhishekMallela $I-A^k=I-0 = I$